# How to transfer xml file from postman to web api using post method and return it back?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlhttprequest, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

[Here I have the request body. P.s. Content-Type: text/xml in headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvSYw.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <QRY Card="0000" Restaurant="0000" UnitNo="00">
        <INPBUF>
            <CHECK stationcode="0" restaurantcode="00" cashservername="00" generateddatetime="0000-00-0000:0000:00:00">
                <EXTINFO>
                    <INTERFACES>
                        <INTERFACE type="0" id="0" mode="0">
                            <HOLDERS>
                                <ITEM cardcode="0000000"/>
                            </HOLDERS>
                        </INTERFACE>
                    </INTERFACES>
                </EXTINFO>
            </CHECK>
        </INPBUF>
    </QRY>
</ROOT>
```

This is the post method, which must be modified in such a way as to accept the request sent by post and return its body back.
**The request is sent to the asp.net core web api project.**

```
// POST api/<controller>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {


    }
```

[On most attempts, I got the following result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04gxA.jpg)

**1) What type of function parameters should be used ?** 
**2) What type, function should return ?**
**3) Should I create my own Xml class that will be used as the parameter type of the function ?**

Comment: You have to encode html special character using : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and then decode using System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 415 Unsupported media type,you need to check below:

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

> 1) What type of function parameters should be used ?

And if you want to get the default xml,you need to change the parameter type `string` to `XElement`:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]XElement request)
{
   //do your logic..
}
```

[image]

> 2) What type, function should return ?

It is just up to you.You could return the corrosponding data whatever you want to get from the xml.

> 3) Should I create my own Xml class that will be used as the parameter type of the function ?

You could create your own class and get the xml like below:

1.User Class:

```
public class User
{  
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]User user)
{
    var response = new User
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Sandy"
    };
    return Ok(response);
}
```

3.Postman(if you want to get a response in XML format you have to add header `Accept application/xml` cause the default is json. ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<User>
   <Id>1</Id>
   <Name>aa</Name>
</User>
```

4.Result:
[image]

Reference:http://www.devcode4.com/article/asp-net-core-xml-request-response